# Why can't I reuse a custom validator in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a custom validator in lib/validators/past_validator.rb that looks like that:

```
class PastValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    (record.errors[attribute] << "must be in the past") if value >= Date.today
  end
end
```

I required this in application.rb like so:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config_root}/lib/validators)
```

I want to use this validator in two models user and photo. A user has a birthday(date) and a photo has a date-attribute 'taken_on', both must be in the past.

In user.rb I have the following line:

```
validates :birthday, allow_nil: true, past: true
```

The validation of birthday works like charm here.

In photo.rb:

```
def self.new_photo(params)
  photo = new(taken_on: (Date.parse params[:taken_on]) ) 

  photo
end

validates :taken_on, presence: true, past: true
```

If i comment out "past: true", this also works, but if not i get NoMethodError. The backtrace showed me, that value is not set in the validator, so the interpreter thinks value must be a method and gives me a NoMethodError. But why is value not set?

I already tried to do the following in photo.rb:

```
def self.new_photo(params)
  date = Date.parse params[:taken_on]
  p date # Gives me a correct instance of Date
  photo = new(taken_on: date)

  photo
end

validates :taken_on, presence: true, past: true, on: :create
```

The strange thing is that validation happens already when i instanciate a photo.

Comment: Why do you have this `new_photo` method? That thing shouldn't exist in your model. That's a controller concern.

Comment: You have a typo, 'config_root' should be 'config.root'

Comment: I don't agree with you tadman, that's nothing wrong having that in model, it follows 'fat models, skinny controllers' principle

Comment: To say the truth new_photo normally does a lot more, but I extracted the code for test purposes in a new project... The error happens even there.